# Can I execute a Python file in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, python, uwp, execute

I want to execute a Python 3.5 file in my UWP application.

The App is just for my personal use, so it doesn't need to run on any pc. 
I want to execute the Python file with the installed Python interpreter; So no need for IronPython (I know that doesn't work with UWP).

The Python script can be handled as a black box. I just want to run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not in pure UWP app as this does not allow you to start processes, which would be necessary to get the Python interpreter running. Luckily, there are alternatives.

One is to launch a full-trust process from your UWP app which can be a console app with Iron Python and which will execute the script. See **[great series of blog posts by Stefan Wick](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/)** on implementing Full Trust.

Alternatively, you can use the [UWP Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) to do what you need. This way you can build a **classic desktop application** (for example with WPF), install the **Iron Python** package from NuGet and execute your script right from the app. You can then package the result as a UWP. Thanks to the Desktop Bridge you can then **distribute the app** normally via the **Microsoft Store**.

Comment: Great, let me know how it goes then :-) .

Comment: Basically, my app opens another app via the bridge. This app then executes  my Python script?

Comment: That is actually an alternative - see great series of posts by Stefan Wick - https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/ . Using a Full-Trust extension you can launch a desktop app which will do the heavy lifting of running Iron Python.

Comment: My original answer used a different route - building a desktop app which is then packaged as UWP

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I executed the steps from the blog and got my code to work like intended. I found another solution for another problem though, so I didn't need to execute a Python file. I was able to solve the problem directly in the console app like it is described in the blog.

Comment: Great :-) . Please consider accepting the answer as solution, so the question is closed. Happy coding!